# Easy way to check that a matrix is positive definite or not.

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite

Consider a matrix $A=(a_{ij})_{5\times 5}$ , $1\le{i,j}\le5$ such that 
$a_{ij} = \dfrac{1}{n_{i}+n_{j}+1}$ where $n_{i}$ and $n_{j}$ are natural numbers. Then which of the following cases A is positive definite matrix?

1. $n_{i} = i$ for all i=1,2,3,4,5
2. $n_{1}<n_{2}<.....<n_{5}$
3. $n_{1}=n_{2}=.....=n_{5}$
4. $n_{1}>n_{2}>.....>n_{5}$

My Attempt : for option third, observe that, all entries of matrix will be equal, this gives A has zero as eigen value, so not positive definite. 
For other options, I have only way that putting Particularl values of $n_{i}$ and $n_{j}$and find out eigen values of A or using sylvester's criterion .
But this approach of problem solving is much long as well as much calculation.
Any better approach , please help me. 
Thanks

Comment: Hint: there is another formula for $a_{ij}$ that you can use to give instant no-brainer answers to your questions. One from a different branch of mathematics that you have probably studied.

Comment: @kimchilover I considered your hint and I am stumped. Could you perhaps explain a bit more how one would otherwise express $a_{ij}$?

Comment: $\int_0^1 x^m\,dx = 1/(m+1)$ for all $m> -1$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $n_k>-1$,
$$ A = \int B(x)\,dx \qquad\text{where}\qquad B(x)_{ij}=x^{n_i}\cdot x^{n_j}\qquad $$
and $B(x)=C(x)\cdot C(x)^T$ and $C(x)_{ij} = x^{n_i}$. Like any real matrix of the $CC^T$ form, $B$ is positive semi-definite, and so it is $A$, which is a principal minor of a [Hilbert matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix). The order of $n_1,\ldots,n_5$ cannot affect the positive-definiteness of $A$ or the lack of it, since you may always assume $n_1\leq n_2\leq n_3\leq n_4\leq n_5$, up to mapping $A$ into $\Pi^{-1} A \Pi=\Pi^{T} A \Pi$ with $\Pi$ being a permutation matrix.

Comment: Sir, I'm not able understand your solution. This is beyond my knowledge. Any easy approach?